# how to economize jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, selector

Probably a stupid question, but I couldn't find a direct answer, so how can I change `":not('#home div, .nav')"` in to something like `":not('this div, .nav')"`? That would allow me reuse the same function for different objects.

```
 $( "#home" ).click(function() {
     $("#content .plates").children(":not('#home div, .nav')" ).fadeOut(700);     
    });
```

and here is the HTML if needed:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="content">
  <div id="home" class="plates">
   <div class="nav"></div>
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div id="two"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="about" class="plates">
   <div class="nav"></div>
   <div id="three"></div>
   <div id="four"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: _(":not('div, .nav')")_ ... doesn't work?

Comment: `$( "#wrapper #content #home" ).` makes not much sense to write since IDs are unique, so just write `$( "#home" ).`

Comment: I think it doesn't, because that wouldn't fade divs in "about". I need to exclude only children of "home", but I want to refer to "home" as "this" so that I could use the same code for "about" only changing the id in the first line of code. sorry for being not very clear :)

Comment: vsync - you are right, don't know why I did that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP is asking for something generic that can be reused on both the "home" and the "about" divs (and maybe on others to be added later?). But, for each one, excluding the "nav" item from the fadeout. So try this:

```
function myFunc( clickableItem) {
    $(".plates:not(" + clickableItem + ")").children( ":not('.nav')" ).fadeOut(700); }

$( "#home" ).click( function(){
    myFunc( "#home");
});

$( "#about" ).click( function(){
    myFunc("#about");
});
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough, I needed to fade everything but the children of the clicked item and `.nav` in other divs, but thanks for your help :)

Comment: O, I see now. No matter, the principle's just the same - I've edited the line in myFunc to use a different selector. A more complicated one - quite an interesting one really! - but it should do exactly what you want hopefuly.

Comment: GuyH, that looks great! which one would work faster, yours, or the one above, by  CupawnTae?  If there is any difference, could someone explain why? sorry for beginner's questions :D

Comment: So far as the user is concerned they would not see any difference in speed between the two - both solutions are working clientside, in the JavaScript. Speed really only becomes inportant if you have things repeated hundreds of times in a loop, or lots of requests to the server. Just choose whichever of the solutions best suits your programming needs in your coding.

Answer (score 1):

In the handler, `this` will be the clicked element, so you could just use this:

```
$( "#home" ).click(function() {
   $("#wrapper #content .plates").children(":not('#"+this.id+" div, .nav')" ).fadeOut(700);     
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) `:not()`, but you can also use [jQuery chained function `.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), which subtracts matched elements from another set of matched elements.

The usage is like this:

```
$(selector1).not(selector2).fadeOut(700);
```

Where elements in `selector2` will get substracted from set matched by `selector1`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the top. Provided you follow the spec and IDs are unique on your page (as they should be), your click event selector should be just

```
$("#home").click(function() {...});
```

Also, the inner selector should be

```
$("#content .plates").children(...);
```

There's no need to stack ID selectors in front of other ID selectors since IDs should be unique and selectors are parsed from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the clicked element.

Code:

```
$("#wrapper #content #home").click(function () {
    $("#wrapper #content .plates").children(':not(.nav)').not($(this)).fadeOut(700);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dms6u1ww/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#wrapper #content #home" ).click(function() {
    $("#wrapper #content .plates").children().not($('div', this)).not('.nav').fadeOut(700);  
});
```